# Fancyupload 3.0 - Attach-a-file

Tags: php

I'm trying to add some more features to this(Attach a file): http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/3-0/showcase/attach-a-file

Does anybody know how to configure this so that you can pass in through the html page where to save the uploads? ie a folder name?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Send it in the query string i.e. upload.php?folder=ABC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class Swiff.Uploader has several options, as an argument, where you can specify the URL to upload to and several other tweaks. Check the documentation at http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/ , it describes most possible options and events.